# Disable automatic scroll in UICollectionView if user is scrolling

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift4

I have implemented an horizontal `UICollectionView` which scrolls automatically to the next cell after 3 seconds.

Everything works as expected, but I have ran into an issue.

Since the function fires automatically after 3 seconds, with a `NSTimer` it colides with the user's scroll if both occur at the same time.

Example:

User is scrolling left (backwards) at the same time the 3 second function fires, which will scroll to the right (next cell).

I am wondering if there's a way to let's say, disable the automatic scroll if the user himself is scrolling, and re-enable it after a few seconds, if the user stopped scrolling.

Here's my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    startTimer()
}

fileprivate func startTimer() {
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3.0, target: self, selector: #selector(scrollToNextCell), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc fileprivate func scrollToNextCell() {
    let cellSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    let contentOffset = collectionView.contentOffset
    if collectionView.contentSize.width <= collectionView.contentOffset.x + cellSize.width {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cellSize.width, height: cellSize.height)
        collectionView.scrollRectToVisible(rect, animated: false)
    } else {
        let rect = CGRect(x: contentOffset.x + cellSize.width, y: 0, width: cellSize.width, height: cellSize.height)
        collectionView.scrollRectToVisible(rect, animated: true)
    }
}
```

What's the best approach here?

Something along:

Collection view detects user scroll it disables the `startTimer()` function, then if the user stops scrolling, fires another function that waits `Xn seconds` to fire the `startTimer()` function again.

Then every time the user scrolls again, it disables again the `startTimer()` and the new function that enables the `startTimer()` if it was running.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of the `UIScrollViewDelegate`

```
// called on finger up as we are moving
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    Invalidate Timer.
}

// called when scroll view grinds to a halt  
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    Restart Timer.
}
```

**Alternative Approach**:

Make use if `decelerating`property. It returns `YES` if user isn't dragging (touch up) but scroll view is still moving.

```
@objc fileprivate func scrollToNextCell() {
  if (!collectionView.isDecelerating) {
     //your code here
  }
}
```

Comment: Ohh.. didn't knew that the `Decelerating` properties only fired on touch, since it was automatically scrolling I thought they'd fire anyway. I'll try your solution and I'll feedback in a moment.

Comment: Thank you very much